# Sending pdf files to printer via windows service

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, windows-services

We need to send pdf files to printer directly via a windows service.

Our scenario is : Our watcher windows service will watch a particular folder and as soon as a new PDF file is created ( copied ) in that folder it should be sent to the default printer directly.

We have tried to open adobe.exe process via windows service to achieve this but we were not successful. We also tried to run a batch file via windows service but it was not working as well. Seems like we cannot open a process via a windows service at all as per windows security rules (Machine is running windows server 2008).

Can someone help us on how to achieve this kind of direct printing.
We do not necessarily need to print in the background. Even if we can open the adobe print dialog box (or any other print selection dialog) its ok.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

My guess is create small application hidden in system tray, connect it to your service with WCF and then print it using this : [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

But this is my wild guess ...

Answer (score 0):

If you setup the Windows Service to run as a Local Service account and check the the box to allow it to interact with the desktop, then you should be able to start a shell process calling the Adobe or Foxit reader and pass the appropriate command line arguments.  Worked great for us until we needed to move to a domain account for the service